# « Les réponses sont contradictoires » ou « Les réponses se contredisent l’une l’autre »?

Tags: choix-de-mot, formulation-idiomatique, formulation, reformulation

En parlant non pas d’une réponse qui se contredit elle-même, mais de deux voire de plusieurs réponses qui rentrent en contradiction entre elles.

> Toutes les réponses que j’ai reçues se contredisent entre elles et pour couronner le tout, certaines se contredisent elles-mêmes/sont en contradiction avec elles-mêmes.

Les propositions/reformulations sont les bienvenues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tes deux propositions sont bonnes.

En voici une autre :

> Non seulement les réponses que j'ai reçues se contredisent les unes les autres mais certaines vont jusqu'à être incohérentes avec elles-mêmes.